# Why doesn't this Firefox extension code work with prompt or alert for contextMenus?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have the following `background.js` script:

```
browser.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
  browser.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'add-todo',
    title: 'Add a todo',
    contexts: ['page']
  });
});

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (clickData) {
  if (clickData.menuItemId === 'add-todo') {
    var todoName = window.prompt('Add a todo')

    alert(todoName);
  }
});
```

And the following `manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Todo",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Yet another todo app",
  "browser_action": { "default_popup": "index.html" },
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

I can see the context menu when I right click, but clicking it does nothing.

Oddly, when I open the extension via the browser action button, and it displays my `popup.html`, I can right click there and see a prompt dialog.

I use the same code in Chrome with the `webextension-polyfill` library and it works just fine.

What gives with Firefox?

Comment: FF doesn't allow alert/prompt/confirm in background scripts. Debug the script in the debugger, see the [documentation](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/debugging/).